# How to add a Layout to another Layout in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How can I go about adding a Layout to another Layout?

How can add a Layout written in Java to another Layout. In this case I would like to add `new RevAppBarLayout().getRevAppBarLayout(this);` to a DrawerLayout called drawer.

```
DrawerLayout drawer = new DrawerLayout(this);
drawer.addView(inflatedLayout);
```

---

```
public class RevAppBarLayout extends MainActivity {

    public AppBarLayout getRevAppBarLayout(Context context) {
        AppBarLayout revAppBarLayout = new AppBarLayout( context );
        Toolbar revToolBar = new Toolbar( context );

        setSupportActionBar(revToolBar);

        return revAppBarLayout;
    }
}
```

This is how to do it if it were an XML fragment:

```
AppBarLayout revAppBarLayout = new RevToolBar().getRevAppBarLayout( this );

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 View inflatedLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null, false);
 drawer.addView(inflatedLayout);
```

Comment: Why does a Fragment matter? `View.addView` is the method, and you already seem to be using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you add drawer to your layout? Because it's not retreived from your layout, you are instantiating it dynamically as a new object.

And you don't need an inflater to add layout or view to another layout. If it's activity get the layout(RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, etc.)using `findViewById(R.id.layoutContainer);` then add any view you want to this layout using addView.